# How do loop to a new random generation after the first has been answered correctly?

Tags: java

I have figured out how to get my program to generate a random multiplication question and loop until it is answered correctly, however I need the program to generate another different multiplication question after the previous one is answered correctly...any tips would be appreciated.

```
package cai;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cai {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int varFirst = first(x);
    int varSecond = second(y);
    int answer;

    do {
        System.out.printf("What is %d times %d?%n", varFirst, varSecond);
        answer = input.nextInt();
        if (varFirst * varSecond != answer) {
            System.out.printf("No. Please try again%n");
        }
    } while (varFirst * varSecond != answer);
    System.out.printf("Very good!%n");
}
public static int first(int x) {
    SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
    x = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(10);

    return x;
}
public static int second(int y) {
    SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
    y = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(10);

    return y;
}
}
```

Comment: You clearly know how to use loops already. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Just wrap your code into another loop with a question whether the user wants to start over or not. Not the whole code of course... I think you can figure it out

Comment: You don't need `SecureRandom` for this. The standard `Random` would be fine. --- Other than that, you already figured out how to use loops, so the answer should be obvious to you: Wrap with another loop.

Comment: If it's important to have a _different_ problem every time, you can keep a list of the problems you've already asked.  To come up with a new problem, keep generating pairs of random numbers until you get a pair that's not on the list.

Comment: Thanks for the help, was able to add another loop to get it to work.  Additional question: what would I add to ask the user after each correct answer if they'd like another question?  Do I use another loop around the whole thing or a combination of if statements?

Comment: No, for that you just need a `print(question)` + "`if(input==break_condition) break;`" on the loop you've just created.

Comment: @AlmightyR he's only using the numbers 1-10, not every possible 'int'.  That's at least a 1/100 chance of repeating a question: small, yes, but hardly insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the problem has already been answered in the comments section, and the OP has already reached a working solution, I think I'll have some ***FUN™*** and maybe give some points of reference to boost his learning of code quality...

Just for reference, the answer to the question was a simple:

> Wrap another loop around it!

---

So here we go! How the code would look like if **I** (some years of professional experience with Java, but **disclaimer:** away from it for a while and doing this from memory without editor) were implementing it:

```
public class Cai {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //There is no need for those 'x' and 'y' variables.
        //You're ultimately not using them anyway.

        int first;
        int second;
        int answer;

        //There IS gain in caching result (expected answer) to avoid repeated calculations.
        int expectedAnswer;

        do {
            do {
                //First, second, and expected answer are "part of the question logic".
                //It makes more sense to assign their values here, at start of a new question.
                first = getOperand(10); //One method, used twice.
                second = getOperand(10); //Bonus, now you can choose bound here.
                expectedAnswer = first * second;

                //Question itself; repeat till right answer.
                System.out.printf("What is %d times %d?%n", first, second);
                answer = input.nextInt();
                if (answer != expectedAnswer)
                    System.out.printf("No. Please try again.%n");
            } while (answer != expectedAnswer);
            System.out.printf("Very good!%n");

            //As if user wants another question.
            //Repeat till answer is one that is recognized and can be handled.
            String keepGoing;
            do {
                System.out.printf("Do you want to answer another one? (y|n)%n");
                keepGoing = input.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
                if(keepGoing != "y" && keepGoing != "n")
                    System.out.printf("Sorry. I don't understand. I was expecting 'y' or 'n'...%n");
            } while (keepGoing != "y" && keepGoing != "n");
            //Here, answer if be either "y" or "n".
            //If it's "n", then quit the loop with break.
            //If it's not "n", then it's a "y"; do another question.
            if(keepGoing == "n")
                break;
        } while (true);
    }

    //There is no need for two functions performing the same action.
    //Make one method and use it twice instead.
    public static int getOperand(int bound) {
        //This doesn't need cryptographic safety. Normal Random is fine.
        Random rng = new Random(); //rng = Random Number Generator
        return rng.nextInt(bound) + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change while loop to something like this

```
while(true) { System.out.printf("What is %d times %d?%n", varFirst, varSecond); answer = input.nextInt(); if (varFirst * varSecond != answer) { System.out.printf("No. Please try again%n"); return;} }
```